# pass arguments to remote shell in ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

for example:

```
ssh localhost echo *([^.])
```

requires me to pass -O extglob to the remote shell bash like so:

```
ssh localhost -O extglob echo *([^.])
```

however, ssh then thinks the -O is for itself, so I try again:

```
ssh localhost -- -O extglob echo *([^.])
```

but then bash thinks -- is for itself.

how can I pass -O extglob to bash through ssh?

thanks.

update: i would prefer not to ask ssh to ask bash to launch another bash:

```
ssh yourserver bash -O extglob -c "'echo *([^.])'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: As mentioned in the comments the extglob will lead to a syntax error. I've managed it by piping the command to stdin:

```
ssh yourserver -- bash -O extglob <<'EOF'
echo *([^.])
EOF
```

---

I would start an additonal shell remotely. Like this:

```
ssh yourserver bash -O extglob -c 'ls -al'
```

Although it is not required in *this* example I would advice you to use `--` after ssh arguments (as you mentioned):

```
ssh yourserver -- bash -O extglob -c 'ls -al'
```

This will prevent ssh from parsing the command to execute remotely as arguments.

---

But you can also pass the option to the shell ssh itself starts for you using the `shopt` bash builtin. Note that `;` separates the two commands.

```
ssh yourserver -- 'shopt -s extglob; ls -al'
```

Comment: have you tried any of those with the *([^.]) ?  `syntax error near unexpected token '('`.  i don't need extglob if it's a simple `ls -al`.

Comment: if i'm going to run bash myself, then wouldn't it be easier to do `ssh yourserver bash -O extglob -c "'echo *([^.])'"`

Comment: Yes thats working too, but might get messy if the command gets more complex

Comment: `ssh yourserver bash -O extglob -c 'ls -al'` unfortunately doesn't work the way you'd hope; ssh combines arguments in a manner equivalent to `$*`, so you get `$SHELL -c 'bash -O extglob -c ls -al`

Comment: Compare to `ssh yourserver $'bash -O extglob -c \'ls -al\''`, which _does_ work as intended.

Comment: `shopt -s extglob; echo *([^.])` isn't reliable either, because at least some versions of bash run the whole line through the parser, so parser configuration changes don't take effect until parsing of the next line starts. See more discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49283740

Comment: @Jayen, I'd strongly suggest `ssh yourserver "bash -O extglob -c 'echo *([^.])'"`n, so the _entire remote command_ is passed as a single string. Easier to reason about when that's explicit, instead of letting it get munged into a string by ssh later.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy at some point you want to copy a script across and execute it, and not try to do it in one command.