# Bash script throws syntax errors when the 'extglob' option is set inside a subshell or function

Tags: bash

## Problem

The execution of a Bash script fails with the following error message when the 'extglob' option is set inside a [subshell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html):

```
/tmp/foo.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail
(
    shopt -s extglob
    for f in ?(.)!(|+(.)|vendor); do
        echo "$f"
    done
)
```

It fails in the same manner inside a [function](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

list_no_vendor () {
    shopt -s extglob
    for f in ?(.)!(|+(.)|vendor); do
        echo "$f"
    done
}

list_no_vendor
```

## Investigation

In both cases, the script executes successfully when the option is set globally, **outside** of the subshell or function.

Surprisingly, when set locally, the 'extglob' option appears to be effectively enabled in both the subshell and function:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

(
    shopt -s extglob
    echo 'In the subshell:' "$(shopt extglob)"
)

list_no_vendor () {
    shopt -s extglob
    echo 'In the function:' "$(shopt extglob)"
}

echo 'In the main shell:' "$(shopt extglob)"

list_no_vendor
```

Output:

```
In the subshell: extglob            on
In the main shell: extglob          off
In the function: extglob            on
```

This makes the syntax error extremely puzzling to me.

## Workaround

Passing a heredoc to the `bash` command works.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

bash <<'EOF'
    shopt -s extglob
    echo 'In the child:' "$(shopt extglob)"
EOF

echo 'In the parent:' "$(shopt extglob)"
```

Output:

```
In the child: extglob           on
In the parent: extglob          off
```

However I would be curious to understand the gist of the problem here.

Comment: BTW, `set -e` is rather widely frowned on. See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), skipping the allegory for the exercises below if in a hurry, and https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/, listing incompatibilities (of which there are many) amongst different shells' implementations of same.

Comment: Beyond my rather terse answer -- I don't understand what the surprise is here. Could you be more clear about how your mental model and actual behavior conflict? (That flags are inherited by subshells should be entirely unsurprising, whether or not they were enabled within a function context; that flags set in a function are not cleared on leaving it, likewise, doesn't contradict any documentation I'm aware of, and thus should likewise be expected).

Comment: I understand that flags are inherited. I am surprised because I was expecting my syntax to be valid in the context of my subshell (and invalid outside of it).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`extglob` is a flag used *by the parser*. Functions, compound commands, &c. are parsed in entirety ahead of execution. Thus, `extglob` must be set *before* that content is parsed; setting it at execution time but after parse time does not have any effect for previously-parsed content.

This is also why you can't run `shopt -s extglob; ls !(*.txt)` as a one-liner (when `extglob` is previously unset), but must have a newline between the two commands.

---

Not as an example of acceptable practice, but as an example demonstrating the behavior, consider the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
(
    shopt -s extglob
    # Parse of eval'd code is deferred, so this succeeds
    eval '
        for f in ?(.)!(|+(.)|vendor); do
            echo "$f"
        done
    '
)
```

No such error takes place here, because parsing of the content passed to `eval` happens only *after* the `shopt -s extglob` was executed, rather than when the block of code to be run in a subshell is parsed.

Comment: I'll add for clarify that shopt -s extglob needs to run before the current context, not just the current line. I had a case where my need for extglob was inside an 'if' and so shopt -s extglob had to be run outside the 'if'. Placing it above the needed line was not enough (received the same error "...unexpected token `('".