# How to control when glob is expanded, pass glob into bash script from sh and then expand it

Tags: bash, shell, glob

I am trying to run some code in a CI system

Bash 5 is available but the initial command is run from `sh`

I think I need bash features

This prints literal `**/*.json`:

```bash
bash -c 'echo **/*.json'
```

This works:

```bash
bash -c 'shopt -s globstar; echo **/*.json'
```

This gives "syntax error near unexpected token `('":

```bash
bash -c 'shopt -s extglob; echo **/*.@(yml|yaml)'
```

I found this answer which suggests the reason for the syntax error https://stackoverflow.com/a/49283991/202168

i.e. `globstar` is fine in a one-liner but the same doesn't work for `extglob` because blah blah something to do with the parser.

So I tried creating a wrapper script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s globstar
shopt -s extglob

exec "$@"
```

And to call it:

```bash
wrapper.sh 'echo **/*.@(yml|yaml)'
```

but it seems as if the glob is not expanded, I get "No such file or directory".

Alternatively:

```bash
wrapper.sh echo '**/*.@(yml|yaml)'
```

just echoes literal `**/*.@(yml|yaml)`

And:

```bash
wrapper.sh echo **/*.@(yml|yaml)
```

gives "syntax error" again, I assume because now the `sh` is trying to parse the glob part before it gets to the bash wrapper.

How do I pass the glob into the wrapper script so that it is expanded in the bash wrapper before calling `echo`?

(I am looking for solutions to this, not for alternative ways to list yml or yaml files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (the reason is explained in the answer you found):

```
bash -c 'shopt -s extglob globstar
echo **/*.@(yml|yaml)'
```

Please note the literal newline character, instead of `;`, inside single quoted command string.

Comment: unfortunately this seems to just echo literal `**/*.@(yml|yaml)`

Comment: my mistake, the problem was just that no yaml files were found - this answer works fine

Comment: How do you tell the difference between a filename with a space in it in the output from this code and two separate files? How do you handle the case where someone ran `d='./ /etc/passwd '; mkdir -p -- "$d" && touch "$d/hi.yml"`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use bash here-doc like this:

```bash
bash -s <<-'EOF'
shopt -s extglob globstar
echo **/*.@(yml|yaml)
EOF
```

Comment: unfortunately this seems to just echo literal `**/*.@(yml|yaml)`

Comment: This worked fine on my bash prompt

Comment: Hmm, yes it does for me too, but not in the CI. Would printing the literal be the symptom if no files were found by expanding the glob?

Comment: When I run locally I am on macos so I have a zsh shell, and when I run bash from there it is v3.2.  In the CI it is a sh shell launching bash v5.  Are there any other shopt options that might need to be set for this to work as expected?

Comment: @Anentropic To make sure it's not because there were no matching files, you can try the `nullglob` (expand to empty string if nothing matches) or `failglob` (error if nothing matches) shell options.

Comment: @Anentropic : If a glob does not expand, bash uses the literal string containing the globs, unless you set the option _nullglob_. In your case, for getting further insight in the matter, I would do inside your heredoc a plain `shopt`, just to see the state of all options, and then just a `echo *`, to see what entries you have in your working directory.

Comment: @Anentropic: What do you mean by _CI_? Continuous integration? In this case it would be helpful to know which CI you are using, and how you are calling your code from the CI-configuration.

Comment: @user1934428 yes, continuous integration - it's BuildKite. I am making a `command` step in a buildkite pipeline

Comment: @Anentropic: Please update then your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the tips... running with `failglob` gives `no match: **/*.@(yml|yaml)`. I have realised now that this is because the yaml files found locally aren't being sent to the CI environment ‍♂️. So this answer works perfectly. I have upvoted it, but I feel obligated to accept the other one which also works and was posted a bit earlier.