# ssh: bash: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am trying to execute this command on remote server via ssh:

```
ssh test@1.1.1.1 "cd /home/testuser/testing; rm -rf !('testfolder')" &
```

When I execute this line I get this error:

```
bash: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: This is syntax that only works when the extglob optional feature is enabled. You need to run `shopt -s extglob` **before** the command enters the parser

Comment: See also [bash script throws syntax errors when extglob option is set inside a subshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49283740/bash-script-throws-syntax-errors-when-the-extglob-option-is-set-inside-a-subsh)